# Do chrome extensions that "read content of all web pages" also have Internet access?

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, google-chrome-extensions

I'm considering installing a chrome extension that can apply <del>strikethrough</del> text in any textarea.  The permissions say it can "read the contents of all websites".

I'm OK with that, unless the extension can *also* make socket connections and send data to the developers or others.

How do Chrome permissions work in this regard?  If an extension did send data, how could I tell or track the data flow?

Comment: Similar question for Firefox: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/254305/44259

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, you specify which [permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions) your browser extension requires in order to function. (And it should be the absolute minimum required.)

As a user, you ought to [understand the permissions](https://www.maketecheasier.com/chrome-extension-permissions-explained/) a developer indicates their Chrome extension "requires" so you can make an informed decision whether to install. Ironically, there is an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-extensions-de/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc) that may help.

Further, it would be a bit naive to conclude that browser extensions are basically equal. That is, the extension framework for the Mozilla FireFox browser is likely to steer more toward end-user privacy than the extension framework that Google created for Chrome.

If you really want to know who your extension may be talking to, in any browser, become comfortable using the browser's *dev tools*, in this case, the [Network Monitor](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/). Open up the panel and interact with your extension to see what network calls it may be performing. To track the data flow, get as close to your browser's network traffic as possible, because there is no other way to really know.